# Creating a regular pentagon

Tags: opengl, glut

I am using `OpenGL` and `glut` to create a regular pentagon by using the `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);` function. But the problem is, I'm getting an irregular shape, since it creates each triangle from the centre.

```
// Draw traingle fan
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
//Send the vertices and colors for the pentagon
glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);

glVertex3f(-3.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, -3.0f, 0.0f);

glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f);

glColor4f(0.1f, 0.9f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(2.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```

I'm aware of what and how a pentagon works. i.e-

- three triangles, two equal and one not
- Interior Angles of 108°
- Exterior Angles of 72°
- Area of approximately 1.7204774 × s2 (where s=side length)

But I'm just finding it hard to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to draw it like any other regular n-gon: Distribute n points equally on a circle.

You generate the points in polar coordinate space, with each point having the same radius, and incrementing the angle by (360 / n) for each point.

Roughly:

```
float angleIncrement = 360.0f / n;  // n is 5 in your case
angleIncrement *= M_PI / 180.0f;    // convert degrees to radians
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
float angle = 0.0f;
for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
    glVertex3f(radius * cos(angle), radius * sin(angle), 0.0f);
    angle += angleIncrement;
}
glEnd(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
```

Since this uses the radius as the base input parameter, you'll have to do a little math if the side length is given instead. If you look at the relationship graphically, you can derive the relationship like this (where `s` is the side length, `r` the radius, and `a` the angle named `angleIncrement` in the code above):

```
(s / 2) / r = sin(a / 2)
s / 2 = r * sin(a / 2)
r = s / (2 * sin(a / 2))
```

Comment: Please don't make substantial edits to the question in response to answers. This is not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A repository. It now looks like my answer copied the code from your question.